# Is there a relationship between the properties of different charges of a fundamental particle?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, symmetry-breaking, color-charge

To begin with, I'm a high school student and so my understanding of QFT is quite basic. Due to this, I'd prefer a simple answer (it would be great if it's yes/no) along with a very basic explanation.

Essentially, I know that the three fundamental forces - electric, strong and weak force are results of spontaneous symmetry breaking. At low energies, the symmetry breaks and the forces "split".

My question is based on this. Now that the forces have "split" is there any direct relationship between these forces? For example, an electron has an electric charge of -1, a strong charge of 0, and a weak charge of -1/2. So is there a connection between the -1, the 0 and the -1/2? If one of the values was to change, would any of the other two values change? If yes, would it be both or would it just be one of them?

So in essence, could there exist a fundamental particle that for example has an electric charge of -2, a color charge and a weak charge of 1/2? I'm not sure if there is another restriction that doesn't allow the electric charge to go below -1, but ignoring these other restrictions, just based on the pure relationship between these charges, would changing one affect the other 2, and if it does then is there only a certain number of combinations of these 3 charges?

Comment: The strong force does not (at least within the Standard Model) arise from a symmetry breaking mechanism, so you should restrict your question to electroweak only. For this case, you may want to look up *hypercharge*.

Comment: @NiharKarve oh okay. but even that case, even if the strong force does not arise from symmetry breaking, is there a relationship between all these existing forces such that changing one value changes the others?

Comment: This is not really part of a good answer, *but* .... You might arrange to have such a particle, *however* , for a highly technical reason of consistency of the theory, you'd have to cancel its anomalies, by adding *more* particles performing that function. There is no simple explanation, I fear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you the view from the experiment side:

The model, called the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics, is a mathematical quantum field theory that fits the data up to now and  its predictions are continually   fulfilled.

In addition, the  integral and differential functions of the model have to obey a specific [group theory,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_theory) in order to fit the various measured charges in experiments, that lead to describing the fundamental particles and their composites, that you are asking about.

> [The local SU(3)×SU(2)×U(1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#Theoretical_aspects) gauge symmetry is an internal symmetry that essentially defines the Standard Model. Roughly, the three factors of the gauge symmetry give rise to the three fundamental interactions.

Group theories are as strict as integration and differentiation, once decided upon, one cannot pick and choose the way the particles are represented, but the group theory imposes the specific way charges are combined that allow real particles and composites of particles to exist. One cannot pick and choose among the members of the group.

A good example is the **prediction** that a [particle  called $Ω^-$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_baryon) should exist, that was found experimentally and confirmed the [quark model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quark_model) of the standard model.

[image: omega]

The particle was found and confirmed the theoretical research that led to the development of  the standard model.

So it is not possible to arbitrarily  attach charges to particles, it is the standard model itself as it has developed that does the assignment, in order to agree with observations. If in future experiments observations bring more combinations of the charges that exist in the symmetries of the standard model, the model should change in order to agree with nature , and keep having predictive power.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Also just to be sure, when you say that it is not possible to arbitrarily attach charges to particles, you're referring to both elementary and composite particles right?

Comment: yes, because the possible combinations for composite particles are also constrained by the group representations.  The plot above  is of composite particles, quarks

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: Also one final thing, when you say that it is not possible to arbitrarily attach charges to particles, does that imply that changing the value of one charge will have an effect on the values of the remaining charges?

Comment: It means that you will be destroying the representation, the group symmetry. The theory is valid because it fits the data, you cannot introduce new data to the theory or change the data, and the theory can predict new combinations as the example I  give. Anything new should fit a group representation, it is constrained by the group .

Comment: Yes, I understood that. By my question, I was talking more about the nature of the combinations in the SU(3) x SU(2) x U(1) gauge symmetry, or any other gauge symmetry for that matter. Will changing the value of the charge of any of these groups individually (either SU(3) or SU(2) or U(1)) effect the value of any other charge (given that it is invariant, so not 0)

Comment: The charge value is **experimentally** determined, assuming the standard groups, for the present day data. It cannot be arbitrarily changed. In a theory what was fitted to data could become a variable and allow all sort of fancies, but it will have no connection with our present day universe.

Comment: Yes I get that it is experimentally determined and it has been fit to match our observations. I'm now talking when it comes to predicting new particles, and I'm looking at it in a more theoretical sense. As per the current theory, is it possible for a change in one charge to not affect any of the other charges? Let's say for example there is charge A and charge B. For particle 1, Charge A is -1 and Charge B is 2. Particle B however is not invariant in Charge B. Does this have an effect on the particle's Charge A? Can P1 be (-1,2) and P2 be (-1,0)? Im talking from a theoretical perspective

Comment: The theory is rigid as far as the quantum numbers assigned on the particles in the model. Quantum numbers are fixed, cannot have a fraction of a quantum number in quantum mechanics. there can be multiples, and new composites can be predicted. electric charge at minimum is 0, +/-1/3 +/-2/3  in the model . cannot have another value below this, it will be a new model not describing data

Comment: Oh alright, and a quark being invariant in terms of having a color charge is related to this right? So looking back at my earlier question about P1 and P2, if a particle is not invariant  for a particular transformation, and another particle is invariant for that transformation, can both those particles be similarly invariant in the transformations in which they are both invariant? Eg. P1 being (-1,2) and P2 being (-1,0)? And I'm referring to the current Standard Model

Comment: I cannot answer this , one looks at specific interactions or possible decays and checks whether they are allowed by the quantum number conservations.

Comment: According to the current Standard Model, do these quantum number conservations dictate the possible combination of charges for all the charges? I think my question is more mathematical in terms of symmetry. Different transformations have to be related right? If a particular particle is invariant under a certain transformation, it has to be so for a reason, and so is it mathematically possible for another particle to be similarly invariant under every other transformation bar one? I'm sorry for being so hypothetical, but this is the one thing left that I desparately need to understand

Comment: Maybe this will help http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/allfor.html

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental charges of the Standard Model are actually called "Weak Hypercharge", "Weak Isospin" and "Colour" (the first two "mixes" to produce the weak force and the electromagnetic force, while the third produces the strong force).  However, these 3 charges are independent from each other, in the sense that knowing one of those don't tell me about the other two.

More details (don't read the following if you are concerned about being confused): There are actually 2 different vertex factors for the weak force, corresponding to 2 different weakly interacting bosons (the W bosons and the Z boson).

Comment: So in essence changing the value of one of the charges will have absolutely no effect on the values of the other two charges?

Comment: True, however, the electric charge depends on the weak hypercharge and weak isospin.

Comment: I totally agree with @Photon.  To elaborate on his comment, you can think of the weak hypercharge and the weak isospin as free parameters.  However, to change the electric charge without affecting the weak force and strong force, you need to adjust both the weak hypercharge and the weak isospin simultaneously.

Comment: @TheGypsyKing in your original answer you said that the weak hypercharge and the weak isospin "mix" to produce the weak and EM force. Now, if you change the electric charge and don't want to affect the weak force and strong force you have to adjust the weak hypercharge, spin simultaneously. But if by adjust you mean change, won't that have an effect on the weak force? If the weak and electric charge are results of the mixing of two fundamental charges then how does causing a change in one (electric) not cause a change in the other (weak) in any circumstance?

Comment: @malharb So imagine x=a+b and y=a-b, with both a and b being free parameters.  It is always possible to change x without changing y by adjusting a and b.

Comment: @TheGypsyKing oh okay, that makes sense. So basically, ignoring any other restrictions, a  fundamental particle with any combination of strong charge, electric charge and weak charge can exist?

Comment: @malharb Not completely, because it doesn't make sense to say "a weak charge".  There are two weakly interacting bosons, the W bosons and the Z boson, which depends on the weak isospin and the weak hypercharge differently.  Therefore, there are 3 vertex factors (W boson, Z boson, photon) with only 2 parameters (weak hypercharge, weak isospin).

Comment: @TheGypsyKing Got it. This is a bit off tangent but do the hypercharge and the isospin also "converge" at some point? In the sense that if the weak hypercharge and the weak isospin are fundamental charges, what decides their value? If we're looking at a fundamental particle as a point particle, is it like the energy level of the particle that is the "input" variable that determines the value of all of the charges (in some sort of chain mechanism) ?